# Payment to dapp with text comments best practice

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, wallet, dapp

I am new in eos, so maybe i say something strange.

I want to create a dapp that can receive payments from mobile wallets with text comments.

I imagine this like front end where user type text and hit button.
Then front end connect to dapp to send text and get unique wallet for payment. Credentials for payment on to new wallet is appears at front end. And finally user pay to the wallet using his favorite mobile app.
In such scheme dapp create new unique wallet for each payment.

The key things for such complication is:

1. Identification that concrete payment is for concrete user and text.
2. Compatibility with various mobile wallets.
3. Dapp can access to wallet for his needs.

After investigation I found that there is no simple way to create unique wallet at dapp. This refer to openssl that i can't include from dapp. At this point I understand that I do wrong.

I want to understand on what step I have gone wrong.

1. Maybe there is simpler way to achive payment with comments in dapp.
2. Maybe I don't understand how to use openssl from dapp.
3. Maybe I don't need openssl in my dapp to create new wallet.
4. Something else.

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve but you can use the memo field in the eosio,token contract to store comments or what you can do is modify that contract by adding one more field to it which can be used for storing text comments a simpler solution to start with

Comment: Thanks. Memo field is enough for me.
I just don't see it in my mobile wallet app and this confused me.